# Android Monkey not generating HPROF dump

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

I run the following Android Monkey command:

```
adb shell monkey --hprof -v -p com.my.app 5000
```

It should create a hprof file under /data/misc, but it doesn't.  I chmod'ed 777 /data/misc.

I then tried kill -10 APP_PID, but got the following under logcat:

```
I/dalvikvm(  771): threadid=4: reacting to signal 10
I/dalvikvm(  771): SIGUSR1 forcing GC (no HPROF)
D/dalvikvm(  771): GC_EXPLICIT freed 46K, 38% free 8352K/13383K, external 15387K/15496K, paused 98ms
```

I'm running Cyanogenmod version 7, Android version 2.3.7 on Galaxy S.

Why is there "no HPROF", and how do I get a HPROF dump through Monkey and kill -10?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

When invoked with `--hprof` monkey sends a `SIGUSR1` signal to all the processes, but dumping HPROF data has been disabled from Dalvik by this patch:

> commit b037a464512c0721bdca969ae19cce3d4b17b083 Author: Andy McFadden
>    Date:   Fri Jul 16 11:07:58 2010 -0700
>
> ```
> Don't do heap dump on SIGUSR1.
>
> We still do the GC, but without the HPROF heap dump.
>
> Change-Id: I004a65b9571667dd320dfabec1441d0fc8b9970a
> ```

So, on `SIGUSR1` only GC is invoked.
I guess the `--hprof` option should have to be removed from monkey.